# Why does model.fit require two-dimensional tensors? And why does model.predict not accept scalar tensors?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, neural-network, tensor, tensorflow.js

I was learning TensorFlow.js when I noticed that model.fit has to take in two arguments, input and output, and some configurations. But the inputs were two-dimensional tensors that were written as follows:

```js
let input = tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 1])
```

This looks remarkably like a one-dimensional tensor, written as follows:

```js
let input = tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

And since the two-dimensional tensor was actually a 5 by 1, I decided to replace it with a one-dimensional tensor. However, this completely stopped the program from working. So is there some type of code that says the inputs must be two-dimensional? If so why?

On the topic of multi-dimensional tensors, I also noticed that the model.predict couldn't take in a zero-dimensional tensor, or a scalar. See below

```js
Working Code:

model.predict(tf.tensor1d([6]))

Not Working Code:

model.predict(tf.scalar(6))
```

If anyone can clarify the reasoning behind these limits, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 2D tensor is not a 1D tensor.
`tf.tensor2d([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 1])` is not `tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`. One can be convert to the other but it does not mean that they are equal.

`model.fit` takes as parameter a tensor or rank 2 or more. This tensor can be viewed as an array of elements whose shape are given to the input of the model. The model's `inputShape` is a least of rank 1 which makes `model.fit` parameter to be at least 2(1+1 it is always inputShape's rank + 1).

Since model.fit and model.predict takes as parameter a tensor of the same rank, model.predict parameter is a tensor of rank 2 or more for the same reason outlined above.

However, `model.predict(tf.tensor1d([6]))` works. It does because internally, tensorflow.js will convert the 1D tensor to a 2D tensor. The initial tensor of shape [6], will be converted to a tensor of shape [6, 1].

```
model.predict(tf.tensor1d([6])) 
// will work because it is a 1D tensor 
// and only in the case where the model first layer inputShape is [1]

model.predict(tf.tensor2d([[6]])) 
// will also work
// One rank higher than the inputShape and of shape [1, ...InputShape]

model.predict(tf.scalar(6)) // will not work
```

```js
const model = tf.sequential(
    {layers: [tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]})]});
model.predict(tf.ones([3])).print(); // works
model.predict(tf.ones([3, 1])).print(); // works
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
const model = tf.sequential(
    {layers: [tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [2]})]});
model.predict(tf.ones([2, 2])).print(); // works
model.predict(tf.ones([2])).print(); // will not work
   // because [2] is converted to [2, 1]
   // whereas the model is expecting an input of shape [b, 2] with b an integer
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@latest"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```